# I/flutter (28276): Error found Here DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [404]

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter, dart

## main Page

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
return BlocProvider(create: (context)=> ShopCubit()..getHomeData(),
child: BlocConsumer<ShopCubit,ShopStates>(
    listener: (context,state){},
    builder: (context,state){
      return    MaterialApp(
      theme: lightTheme,
      darkTheme: darkTheme,
themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
home: stateWidget,
);
    },
),);
```

}

## cubit page

HomeModel homeModel;

void getHomeData() {

```
emit(ShopLoadingDataState());
DioHelper.getData(url: home, token: token).then((value) {
  homeModel = HomeModel.fromJson(value.data);
  print(homeModel.toString());
  print(homeModel.status);
  emit(ShopSuccessDataState());
}).catchError((error) {
  print('Error found Here $error');
  emit(ShopErrorDataState());
});
```

}

## DioHelper

import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DioHelper {

static Dio dio;
static init() {

```
dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
  baseUrl: 'https://student.valuxapps.com/api/',
  receiveDataWhenStatusError: true,
));
```

}
static Future getData({

```
@required String url,
Map<String, dynamic> query,
String lang = 'en',
String token,
```

}) async {
dio.options.headers = {

```
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'lang': lang,
  'Authorization': token,
};
return await dio.get(url, queryParameters: query);
```

}

static Future postData({

```
@required String url,
Map<String, dynamic> query,
@required Map<String, dynamic> data,
String lang = 'en',
String token,
```

}) async {

```
dio.options.headers = {

  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'lang': lang,
  'Authorization': token,
};
return dio.post(
  url,
  data: data,
  queryParameters: query,
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

```
dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
  baseUrl: 'https://student.valuxapps.com/api/',
  receiveDataWhenStatusError: true,
))
```

The url you provided is returning 404. Make sure you are providing valid working url.

Comment: working in postman good

Comment: `HomeModel homeModel;

void getHomeData() {

emit(ShopLoadingDataState());
DioHelper.getData(url: home, token: token).then((value) {
  homeModel = HomeModel.fromJson(value.data);
  print(homeModel.toString());
  print(homeModel.status);
  emit(ShopSuccessDataState());
}).catchError((error) {
  print('Error found Here $error');
  emit(ShopErrorDataState());
});
}`  did you try to change home to 'home'

Comment: Still not working